# Not able to access CreateViewController() in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created a content page in xamarin forms and trying to use it in xamarin IOS project using the method CreateViewController() on the xamarin forms page instance but CreateViewController() is not showing up. However, I see that this method can be used on a xamarin forms content page. Why is this method not showing up for me?

Comment: do you have the XF nuget packages installed in your iOS project, and do you have the necessary using statements in your cs file?

Comment: using statement was missing. Thanks. I somehow did not check it.